# Variáveis sensíveis e globais ionic 3 e angular 4

Tags: ionic, ionic3, angular, angularjs-services

Tenho algumas variáveis sensíveis, e o ideal seria deixar todas as variáveis em um so ambiente, quando for necessário mudar, por exemplo de produção para desenvolvimento, esta tarefa se torne fácil.

Ex:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestaurantesProvider {
private url: string = "http://199.169.9.9/ws/ListarEstados.ashx";
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log(this.url);
  }

getRestaurantes(){
  return this.http.post(this.url, null)
  .do(this.logResponde)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.catchError);
}

private catchError(error: Response | any){
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Erro de conexção");
}

private logResponde(res: Response){
  console.log(res);
}

private extractData(res: Response){
  return res.json();
}
}
```

Por padrão gostaria de pegar a `url` que no caso é uma variável sensível para utilizar em todos minhas requisições, deste service e dos outros.

```
private url: string = padrao + "ListarEstados.ashx";
```

Estou tentando utilizar o `AppModule` para este fiz, então fiz assim:

```
export class AppModule {
   private url: string = "http://199.169.0.9/ws/ListarEstados.ashx";

   getUrl(){
     return this.url;
   }
}
```

E na minha `classe` faço assim:

```
private url: string = AppModule.getUrl();
```

O `getUrl()` fica marcado e aparece esta mensagem

> [ts] Property 'getUrl' does not exist on type 'typeof AppModule'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude seu objeto AppModule adicionando o modificador `static`:

```
export class AppModule {
   private static url: string = "http://199.169.0.9/ws/ListarEstados.ashx";

   static getUrl(){
     return this.url;
   }
}
```

E para receber estes dados basta:

```
private url: string = AppModule.getUrl();
```

Lembrando de instanciar a classe, assim:

```
import { AppModule } from '../app/app.module';
```

Comment: Esta avisando que nao esxite o metodo this.url no appModule

Comment: [ts] Property 'url' does not exist on type 'AppModule'

Comment: [ts] Property 'AppModule' does not exist on type 'RestaurantesProvider'.

Comment: Vc importou a sua classe AppModule? `import { AppModule } from './../../model/appModule';`

Comment: realmente não é isto, tentei porém não funcionou

Comment: Vale salientar que estou pegando estes dados do service

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import { MyApp } from '../../app/app.component'
```

no lugar desse `import`.